# Load Balancing on Servers

Tags: php, load

I am looking around to find a PHP Script that can do load balancing. Such as: do.example.com directs to one of eight other servers: d1,d2 and so on. I need a script that can deal with this.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Answer (score 1):

Load balancing can be achieved in a number of different ways.  Doing it in PHP is not usually one of them.

- Apache can be used as a load balancer.
- Nginx can be used as a load balancer.
- All of the big cloud providers off a DNS based load balancer.

Most of these often include extra features like 'health checks' that can tell when a server is not usable.  Where are your servers hosted?  What kind of environment?  This info would help the community offer better suggestions for balancing your application and make it more fault tolerant.

Comment: The server is a game server. It's my friends but I am his Helper Developer. I am not sure currently for the other questions. Can you provide a script in PHP and how I should implant it in the server.